# How to detect numeric overflow/underflow in JavaScript arithmetic operations?

Tags: javascript

I was doing a coding test today, the goal was to catch all edge cases when adding 2 integer representations of strings in JavaScript. One case I could not get was how to detect overflow/underflow for the sum stored in the IEEE 754 numeric.

Normally, in C, I'd look at the binary representation of the numeric, but in JavaScript, I can only look at 32 bits worth of the integer value.

Here's the code I had:

```
function string_add(a, b) {
    if (arguments.length !== 2)
        throw new Error('two arguments expected as input');

    // ensure we have strings
    if (typeof a !== 'string' || typeof b !== 'string')
        throw new Error('bad parameter types');

    // ensure we do not have empty strings
    if (a.length === 0 || b.length === 0)
        throw new Error('an empty string is an invalid argument');

    // ensure we have integer arguments
    if (0 !== (+a % 1) || 0 !== (+b % 1))
        throw new Error('expected numeric integer strings for arguments');

    var sum = +a + +b;      // create numeric sum of a and b.
    sum+='';                // convert numeric sum to string
    return sum;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Edit:  JavaScript now has a [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)***

Actually, integers in Javascript are 53 bits of information due to the way floating point math works.

The last time I needed to do something similar I did...

```
var MAX_INT = Math.pow(2, 53);
var MIN_INT = -MAX_INT;

var value = MAX_INT * 5;
if (value >= MAX_INT) {
  alert("Overflow");
}

// Note. you have to use MAX_INT itself as the overflow mark because of this:
value = MAX_INT+1;
if (value > MAX_INT) {
  alert("Overflow test failed");
}
```

**EDIT** After thinking about it, it would be easier to say:

```
var MAX_INT = Math.pow(2, 53) -1;
var MIN_INT = -MAX_INT;
```

since that is the largest INT that you know hasn't overflowed.

Comment: There are constants for that, `Number.MAX_VALUE` and `Number.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: No.. `Number.MAX_VALUE` is the floating point max **floating point** value, not the max int value.  There is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` in Chrome but I didn't see that documented at MDN.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE

Comment: When I said, "I can only look at 32 bits," I meant using the bit flags.

Comment: True, but you *can* look at more  by treating it as a 64 bit integer and then dividing it into `MSB` and `LSB`.