# Javascript: is there a definite way to tell if the sum of two integers is greater than max int?

Tags: javascript, integer

I am trying to write a test to check if the sum of two arbitrary integers is > 9007199254740992 or < -9007199254740992. Does js consistently behave in a way that is testable when this occurs?

Comment: Start with http://stackoverflow.com/q/23164706/139010 and digest some of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=detect+integer+overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) JavaScript uses [double-precision floating-point format numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) as specified in [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

So the *actual safe bounds* are max == `Math.pow(2,53)-1` and min == `-(Math.pow(2, 53)-1)`. These are encapsulated in the ECMAScript 6 `Number` class constants:

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; // == 9007199254740991
Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER; // == -9007199254740991
```

Taking these limits into account, here's a function that should meet your requirements to show when overflow or underflow can be expected under addition:

```
function additionWillOverflow(x,y) {
    if( y > 0 ) {
        return x > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - y;
    }
    return x < Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER - y;
}
```

And here are 2 illustrative test cases:

```
var x = 9007199254740990;
var y = 3;
console.log( additionWillOverflow(x,y) );    // true
console.log( x + y );                        // 9007199254740992(!) - overflow

x = -9007199254740990;
y = -3;
console.log( additionWillOverflow(x,y) );    // true
console.log( x + y );                        // -9007199254740992(!) - underflow
```

Due to the floating point representation mentioned above, starting at 2^53, javascript can only represent *every second integer*. From 2^54 js can only represent *every fourth integer* and so on. This behaviour should be consistent in any compliant implementation (haven't tested them all) and is the way floating point numbers work (check out [wikipedia for more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)).

Note that calling `isNan(x+y)` or `isFinite(x+y)` return `false` and `true` respectively for *any* numeric values *even when they are outside the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER range* (even when called on an incorrect numeric result).

Hope that helps.